# 'concurrency' error from service when trying to save a second task

Tags: concurrency, rally

I'm trying to save two tasks to the same user story. The first request always succeeds, but the second service request always gets this message back in the response:

> Concurrency conflict: [Object has been modified since being read for
>   update in this context] - ConcurrencyConflictException : Modified
>   since read on update : Object Class : com.f4tech.slm.domain.UserStory
>   : ObjectID :

I am using the JavaScript SDK to create the task. I do this twice:

```
Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({          
    type : 'Task',
    success : function(task) {

        var record = Ext.create(task, {
            Name : taskName,
            State : 'Defined',
            TaskIndex : 1,
            WorkProduct : workProductId,
            Owner : userIdsTeam[owner],
            SyncDevelopmentTasktoAccuRev : accuSync,
            Estimate: hours,
            TargetDeployment: targetDeployment,
            context: {
                  project:'/project/' + currentProjectId,
                  projectScopeDown: true
            },
        });

        record.save({
            callback : afterSaveNewTaskCallback
        });

    }
});
```

Is there anything I can do to get rid of this error and successfully save two tasks?

Comment: How/where is the model create called twice? Is it in response to an event in the UI? Bear in mind that AppSDK calls are asynchronous, so that may account for the concurrency conflict you are encountering. If this is wired up to a button, you may wish to "de-sensitize" the button and only re-sensitize it within the callback for the model.

Comment: I just fixed it, and it did turn out to be a problem with asynchronous calls. I had been calling the method in a loop. I changed it so that I was using a recursive callback. Now I'm not getting the error. Phew. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your tasks are both attached to the same underlying user story the creates are both trying to lock on it to set the association and that's why the second one fails.  You'll need to chain the callbacks together:

```
Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
    type : 'Task', 
    success : function(taskModel) {
        //Create first task
        var task1 = Ext.create(taskModel, {
            //...fields...
        });
        task1.save({
            callback: function() {
                //Create second task
                var task2 = Ext.create(taskModel, {
                    //...fields...
                });
                task2.save({
                    callback: afterSaveNewTaskCallback
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kyle's answer, you can also use the `Rally.data.BulkRecordUpdater` to have the creates/updates queued for you. http://developer.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.BulkRecordUpdater